# how can i perform a pca to one df1 and annotate them based on the treatment from another df?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with samples as columns:

```
sample 1 sample2 sample 3 
1.56285   5.65645  8.56256
```

and i have another dataframe with their annotation such as

```
sample Condition
sample1 tumor
sample2 tumor
sample3 normal tissue
```

how can i perform pca on that using R? i don't know how to connect them

i have tried to connect them but i have many NA values that i cannot remove. My final table look like this:

```
sample1 sample2 sample3 condition
1.56285 NA      NA      Tumor
NA      5.65645 NA      Tumor
NA      NA      8.56256 Tumor
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your main issue right now is how to organize your data in a way that it's useful for applying a PCA, so let's address that first. I assume that you are showing us just the first row of a longer dataframe, in your first block, which I'll call `data`, and that each row corresponds to a different variable (otherwise PCA wouldn't really make sense). First, transpose (`t`) your data so that the columns become rows, then use `merge` to correctly join up your data with the table of sample information (which we'll call `samples`). Here I've made a larger set of example data (20 normal samples , 20 tumor samples, 100 variables (`var1`-`var100`), to show how it can be done:

```
set.seed(1234)  # for reproducible "random" data
data <- data.frame(replicate(20, rnorm(100, mean=10)),
                   replicate(20, c(rnorm(80, mean=10), rnorm(20, mean=50))),
                   row.names=paste0('var', 1:100))
names(data) <- paste0('sample', 1:40)
samples <- data.frame(sample=paste0('sample', 1:40), 
                      Condition=c(rep('normal tissue', 20), rep('tumor', 20)))
data_merge <- merge(t(data), samples, by.x='row.names', by.y='sample')
names(data_merge)[1] <- 'sample'
```

Now we have 40 rows, 102 columns, with first column containing `sample` labels and last column containing `Condition` information. And I've tweaked it so that the values of `var81`-`var100`, for tumor, are larger than those for normal tissue. Let's see if we can visualize that difference by PCA - we will use the `ggfortify` package for easier plotting, as described [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggfortify/vignettes/plot_pca.html):

```
library(ggfortify)
data.pr <- prcomp(data_merge[,2:101], center=T, scale=T)
autoplot(data.pr, data=data_merge, color='Condition')
```

Ta-da!

[image]

Comment: Hello, thank you for your responce! I think I did something similar  such as: [sample_data_t <- t(sample_data)
pca_result <- prcomp(sample_data_t)
custom_colors <- c("blue", "red", "green","purple","yellow")
pca_plot=fviz_pca_ind(pca_result, geom.ind = "point", col.ind = annotation_data$condition, 
             palette = custom_colors) +labs(fill = "Condition")]

Comment: I am trying to add a image here in order to show you the results but I am so new to this and i do not know how to do it :)

Comment: Did it work? If it works, that's all that matters - there are a millions ways to plot PCA results in R!